# can we change image resource dynamically at run time in android?

Tags: android

My question is that,can we change an image present in resources during run time?

For example. i have a image  and i need to replace that image by another image with the same name so that in code we wont get resource not found exception. But image will be different with the same name?

please answer to my question if anybody knows.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to work with resource sourced from the SD card if you want to swap images at runtime.

Comment: You can try it with asset or raw folder. You can not put two images with same name in resources.
pls tell more about what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry..not possible..

Answer (score 0):

> can we change an image present in resources during run time?

No, except by updating the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
res
```

has read-only permission, so the answer is no.